# 'Adjust Last Operation' panel closes when trying to change values

Tags: interface

When you add a new mesh, the overlay appears in the bottom left of the screen allowing you to change certain properties. Recently, however, when I try to click on any setting, the box disappears. I've tried clicking, dragging and any combination of both, but the overlay doesn't respond and vanishes as soon as you release the mouse button.

[image]

Obviously you only get one chance to change these properties - so I'm stuck without it.

Could an add-on be causing the problem?

Comment: Hi. Please add any images using the built-in uploader so the images appear in the body of the question. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The panel seems to be disabled which means global undo might be disabled. Try to search for Global Undo in User preferences (it was in Editing category)

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak - you have solved it! For some reason the Global Undo checkbox in Preferences > System was not checked. As soon as I changed this the Last Operation panel became active. :)

Comment: @MrZak..shouldn't the last operation be adjustable independently of the Undo stack? .. is this reportable?

Comment: @RobinBetts didn't receive notification for some reason. Anyway, it depends on context. Edits in Edit mode will be accessible with Global Undo unchecked but amount of undo steps > 0, actions in Object mode or alike won't be (deleting, scaling, though adding new object for some reason will be accessible). If both are disabled then actions will be unavailable for undoing anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Problem Solved. For whatever reason, the Global Undo checkbox was not ticked (in Preferences > System). Once this had been set the panel started working again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In ay time before some new operation you can call the Adjust Last Operation to display menu for last action performed.

[image: Adjust Last Operation]

Comment: This doesn't help if the panel closes again when they try to edit it, which is the problem they are having.

Comment: If I bring up the the panel again, it remains unresponsive. I can click all over the overlay and nothing happens. I wouldn't swear to it but it seems as if the entire panel is "greyed out" to some degree.